# Set or Update subcollection that behaves like an array

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I have a table of contents collection "toc". I want the "toc" entries to point to the pages contained within a subcollection, e.g.

```
toc
-- camping
----- page1
----- page2
-- fires
----- page2
----- page5
```

I am generating the TOC programmatically and the TOC entry may not exist yet.

I think something along the lines of:

```
await db
      .collection("toc")
      .doc(entry)
      .collection("pages")
      .doc(pageNumber)
      .set(
        {
          pageNumber: [pageNumber],
        },
        {
          merge: true,
        }
      );
```

Basically I want the subcollection to look like an array instead of a collection of documents (I would use an array but the document size of the TOC entry could exceed 1MM).

What is the best way to create a firestore data model that models a table of contents as I'm attempting to describe?

Answer (score 0):

You're fighting the structure of a NoSQL database rather than embracing it.  Two points: you *could* have an array in a document which contains the *IDs* of the documents in the sub-collection - far more manageable, and practical, since there *is no* "listing" of sub-collections (i.e. you c an't ask Firestore (in the client) for a list of sub-collections.

I were I doing this, I would have each document at any particular level have a sub-collection with the consistent name "contains", which has individual documents that are the "pages" - since you *can* query for those documents knowing the sub-collection name.  To reduce reads, you *could* have an array where you stash the *IDs* of those documents, with minimal data such as titles. [Note: repeated use of the sub-collection name "contains" at various levels might complicate collectionGroup queries]

For myself, I wouldn't try to store actual page contents in Firestore, at least not if they are very complex (i.e. not just text) as the size *might* be unbounded.  I'd likely store the actual "page" data over in Firebase Storage, and just keep pointers to them in the above-mentioned array.